# Replacing strings (categories) in a single column that consists of integers, floats and categorical strings - Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I have a Pandas column that contains mostly integers, a bit of floats and some strings like 'yes', 'no' and a few other strings. What can I replace those strings with? Since the column is not completely categorical, I can't do the general one hot encoding or similar. What are best practices in this case?

UPDATE:
For some reason it's not obvious how this column looks like so here is an example:

```
column_name
   1000
    45
    3.0
    yes
    no
    340.0
     p
     k
     4
     .
     .
     .
```

The data is completely made up, the only thing that I need to know what are best practises of dealing with strings like this in a column.

Comment: It will be helpful if you can provide more context! What are you trying to do? What kind of data is it? Can you provide an example / view of the data?

Comment: The question can't be more self explanatory but I added an update.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with this? You could convert strings to numbers if you wanted, if that makes sense, like 'yes' could be 1 and 'no' be 0, but obviously it is not a panda question ,it is a data question: what do the strings mean? and what are you trying to do with the output?
If you're talking NLP type stuff, then you need to encode strings into vectors with something like Word2Vec. For simple string mapping like 'yes/no', binary mapping 1/0 sounds perfectly fine. For the other strings, well, without context of what they mean, it is hard to help.

Comment: the `get_dummies` function I proposed is a generic method to convert categorical data into numbers for ML type tasks.

Answer (score 0):

to map categorical data, you need to use

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html

example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4], 'B': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'C': [1,'e', 'f', 3]})

# all strings:
pd.get_dummies(df['B'])

    a   b   c   d
0   1   0   0   0
1   0   1   0   0
2   0   0   1   0
3   0   0   0   1

# mixed types:
pd.get_dummies(df['C'])


    1   3   e   f
0   1   0   0   0
1   0   0   1   0
2   0   0   0   1
3   0   1   0   0
```

Comment: Yes when the column is only categorical but not when it has mixed ints and string values? If I want to do get_dummies on strings, not sure how to do that or if it is possible.

Comment: do get dummies on that column only. merge into your df, and drop the original colimn

Comment: But in that case all of the numbers will be converted into dummies as well? I don't want numbers to be converted but strings only.

Comment: if you have numbers and strings in the same column, then the numbers are also strings in that column. the dtype is for the entire column. if you have columns with sttings and columns with numbers, apply get_dummies on the string columns only.

Comment: That means that I can't use get_dummies in this case I guess since the entire column is object. Should I just replace strings manually with different numbers then or is there anything else I could do in this case?

Comment: string type shows as object. I don't understand why you have strings and numbers in the same column. you have a data problem not a panda problem

Comment: Well, data is never as you want it to be. That is why I am trying to fix it.

Comment: Then you can either remove all the numbers with regex / convert the numbers to string, then do get_dummies.

Comment: you don't need to do any conversion. get_dummies works with mixed types